# How much memory can I use when preloading textures?

Tags: ios, memory-management, cocos2d-iphone

I am trying to decide if I should preload all of my textures on a loading screen in my game, but I don’t know how much memory I can use for this. I looked around the web and I found where someone said that you can preload all of your textures as long as it is 80MB or under. If this is correct does that mean 80MB on all iOS devices (iPhone 3gs and up)?

Comment: Try it and find out?  Seriously, for a question like this, experience will lead the way.

Comment: I agree that experience is the best way to find out, but is there not a guideline of some kind that I could go off of?

Comment: Bleh.  With Apple, who knows.  I agree this is the right place to ask the question though.  Perhaps add an iOS flag and maybe a C++ flag to get some more eyes on it?

Comment: Instruments should give you pretty good insight into the limits and it will vary by device for sure.  I'm seeing the iPad1 start flagging memory warnings at about 40MB of live memory

Comment: what tool in instruments should i use to show the live memory?

Comment: Use Allocations you'll see the one of the columns "Live Bytes".  Also in the timeline you will see flags get added when memory warning start occurring.

Comment: Please _don't_ add tags just "to get some more eyes on" your question. Use only the tags that describe the question's subject.

Comment: @JoshCaswell I feel that the tags I added were very apropos to the subject!!

Comment: Neither [tag:c++] nor [tag:objective-c] are applicable here; there's neither code nor discussion of language features. Please see the corresponding tag wikis.

Comment: iPad1 has 24MB of texture memory limitation, so you can't load more than 24MB of texture memory at once in iPad1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Only the system knows

Ultimately, this question is all about memory. Apple doesn't care what you are doing with the memory, they just care how much you are using.

There is no 'hard set' limit on how much memory you can use on device X and up. The system (iOS) decides that.

If you are using too much, the system will send you a memory warning. If your memory usage grows, the system will begin to kill background tasks - like music, etc.

If you continue using too much, it will kill *your app*.

This differs between devices. For example, the 3GS has 256 MB of RAM, the 4 and above have 512 MB, and future devices may have more. Adjust accordingly.

So, test your app, watch for memory warnings, and optimize memory usage!

Comment: even the same eevice models behave differently due to different apps and processes running in the background